# How to translate 大好き as a noun/name modifier

Tags: grammar, translation

大好き (*daisuki*): Simply 大 (*dai*, meaning "big, great") added to 好き (*suki*), which is normally either an adjective ("liked, favorite") or a noun ("fondness, favor") but is also idiomatically used in a verb-like capacity to mean "(I) like (you)"; in the case of adjectival use, it would be followed by an appropiate particle to denote its grammatical position (most commonly な *na*). Typically, 大好き would be translated into English as "love".

But how is one supposed to translate a phrase where 大好き is used as a modifier to a noun that comes **after** said modifier (i.e. the order is "modifier-noun"), with no particles whatsoever? Or more specifically, a person's name?

For the specific example that brought me to consider this issue, I've recently encountered a Japanese comic with the title 大好きモーさん *Daisuki Mō-san*; with the premise being about how the eponymous "Mō-san" is in love with someone but does not have the courage to confess on the one hand, and a typical lack of any indication whether said someone reciprocates Mō-san's feelings on the other hand, it seemed to me that the title should be translated as "Mō-san in Love" or something to that effect. However, a few other people that I know argued that the title's structure is grammatically ambiguous enough that "Beloved Mō-san" is an equally valid translation. It is out of my confusion at the logic behind this alternate choice of translation that I come here to seek clarity about the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate the title as

> 大好きモーさん
>   Mo-san who we love

Or in a bit more colloquial English,

> The Mo-san we all love

If I wanted to say something about Mo-san loving someone else, let's say Ms. Tanaka, then I'd write

> 田中さんが大好きモーさん
>   Mo-san who loves Ms Tanaka

### Afterthoughts

After some back and forth with @Sjiveru , I'm very torn about something here.  Japanese grammar essentially wants to put a な between 大好き and モーさん.  Obviously, there's something that works for a title of manga in 大好きモーさん.  I wondered, and now Sjiveru makes me question even more, whether 田中が大好きモーさん parses well in Japanese at all.  Grammar wants the な in there, so it may not even work as a title either.

Comment: So "The Loving Mo-san" wouldn't work?

Comment: no. to get that idea across you'd say something more like やさしいモーさん

Comment: But やさしい means "gentle", not "loving" (in the sense of romantic love, at least).

Comment: While that's true, the *romantic* sense you want to get out of "the loving Mo" isn't really there in English either.  Even in English, "The loving Mo" is more like "Gentle/kind Mo" than anything else.  So, regarding this aspect of your question, I don't know quite how to get "Mo the romancer" (Mr *Ro*meo Mo?)  across in Japanese.

Comment: You need な to make these grammatical as phrases. 大好き**な**モーさん.

Comment: @Sjiveru I know.  I was going to say something like that, but the OP said it was the name of a manga, so I wasn't going to question that much of it.

Comment: @A.Ellett That's fair, especially for the first one. Nonetheless, 田中さんが大好きモーさん is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Sjiveru Yeah, I'd thought about that one too!  :-)  I decided to stick with the wonky syntax nevertheless.

Comment: @Sjiveru Well, consider the fact that the manga One Piece has a character named Montblanc Noland, who is commonly nicknamed "Noland the Liar" -- or, in Japanese, うそつきノーランド (Usotsuki Nōrando). Might this help with translating 大好きモーさん, given うそつき and 大好き seem to be made using the same conjugation method from their root verbs?

Comment: 「大好きモーさん」だけ聞くと、「モーさん、大好き！」「大好きよ、モーさん！」(I love you, Mo san!)って意味かなーと思いますけど。。「チョコレート大好きモーさん」だったら「チョコレートが大好きなモーさん」(Mo san who loves chocolate)って意味かなーと思います。。

Comment: @MarqFJA87 大好き is from [好]{す}き while うそつき is from つく. つく is a verb; 好き is a na-adjective.

Comment: @Sjiveru But 好き is itself derived from the verb 好く, is it not?

Comment: 「うそつき」は人を指して言う名詞で、「嘘つき(の)ノーランド」(ノーランド = a liar)「人殺しの山田」(Yamada = a murderer)「殺人者(の)山田」「食いしん坊の鈴木」とかいうふうに使えますけど、「大好き」って名詞としてそういうふうに使わないですもんね・・

Comment: @MarqFJA87 Ultimately, yes, but I'm not sure that 好く even exists in most varieties of modern standard-ish Japanese. It's fallen out of use long ago. 好き being an adjective is kind of unexpected, anyway - you'd expect that kind of derivation to make a noun.

Comment: @Sjiveru Well, from what I gathered, it belongs to the _i_ form of Japanese verbs, which [has a lot of possible functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#i_form).

Answer (score 0):

Also to me sounds like "The beloved Mō-san", or "Mō-san who we/I love".